# Can a published Web App use HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: google-apps-script

Can a published Web App use HTTP instead of HTTPS?

If so, how do you change the settings to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this today. If you access a web app over HTTP it will immediately get redirected to HTTPS. There are no plans to change this as of now but please log an enhancement request here with details - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list